# What is the solution to use route handlers when dealing with forms in Next.js 13?

Tags: javascript, next.js

Next.js 13 brought with it the route handlers and server action update. I am used to using route handlers when dealing with forms, but it seems that route handlers are not an option anymore?

```
'use server'
import { Product } from "@models/Product";
import clientPromise from "@utils/database";
import { mongooseConnect } from "@utils/mongoose";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req) {
    'use client'
    mongoose.Promise = clientPromise;
    //await mongooseConnect();
    const {title, description, price} = await req.json();
    const productDoc = await Product.create({
      title,description,price,
    })
    return NextResponse.json({productDoc});
  }

  export async function GET(Request) {
    return NextResponse.json({response: "This is a new API route"});
  }
```

I will get one of the two errors and these are to do with the 'use...' actions:

1. Error: Cannot access .create on the server. You cannot dot into a client module from a server component. You can only pass the imported name through.

   This happens when there are not a single 'use...' written and while there are both written
2. Error: Attempted to call POST() from the server but POST is on the client. It's not possible to invoke a client function from the server, it can only be rendered as a Component or passed to props of a Client Component.

   This happens when I write 'use client' on the first line.

Is there are workaround for this or what would be the best course of action here?